# Changing values of each object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to add the additional path information to each javascript object? Like "assets/img/upload/" before each jpg name? That I have url="assets/img/upload/02.jpg" etc.?  That would be great help!

My data right now:

```
[Object { url="02.jpg"}, 
 Object { url="03.jpg"}, 
 Object { url="09.jpg"}, 
 Object { url="04.jpg"}, 
 Object { url="5.jpg"}
 ...]
```

Comment: how are you getting this data in the first place? because you can simply add the url string before the url current value

Comment: This is not a legal javascript data structure.  Where did this come from?

Comment: thanks for asking...its from database table i can't change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
  array[i].url = "assets/img/upload/" + array[i].url;
}
```

Comment: The position of the curly braces: should be on the same line as the for statement to avoid automatic semi-colon insertion. Definitely a must.

Comment: @frenchie, no.  There is no automatic semi-colon insertion in the above code (or any similar loop code).

Comment: @frenchie, I am familiar with automatic semi-colon insertion, and it does not affect syntax like the above.  [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrVXM/1/).  If you find any version of any browser that has semi-colon insertion on that code, let me know.

Comment: @frenchie, the docs make clear that JSlint "looks at some style conventions as well as structural problems."  This is a style preference issue.  The relevant option here is "Tolerate messy white space".  However, I don't agree that this whitespace is messy.  The docs don't mention a connection between this option and semi-colon insertion, and there is none for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your array of objects is called MyArray:

```
for (var i = 0, LoopTimes = MyArray.length; i < LoopTimes; i++) {
       MyArray[i].url = "assets/img/upload/" + MyArray[i].url;
}
```

Note that:

a) the opening curly brace goes on the same line as the `for` statement. See Crokfod on Javascript The Good Parts on youtube for the explanation. In javascript, putting the opening brace on the next line can create some weird bugs that are hard to detect.

b) I cache the length of MyArray in LoopTimes so that I don't have to evaluate the length of the array at every iteration.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the impact of caching the length?  Modern JavaScript VMs are increasingly optimized, so it may be cached or inlined by the VM.  Even if not, that doesn't mean it's a big impact.

Comment: Not benchmarked but for sure at least as fast and probably faster than not caching it and for sure no slower. You might want to google the topic; caching array length is considered best practice.

Comment: I found a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261953/do-modern-javascript-jiters-need-array-length-caching-in-loops) on it.  It seems to be automatically optimized in some browsers, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to be running this code in a modern browser, you could always consider using the `map` method of the `Array` object.

Assuming your array of objects is called "array"

```
array.map(function(item) {return item.url = "assets/img/upload/" + item.url;});
```

This runs the anonymous function, that takes an "item" in the array, and returns the modified url field, over each element of the array.

If you need your code to run on older browsers, stick with the for loops suggested by the other contributors.

Comment: I consider this confusing.  The point of `map` is to return a new array (which you're discarding).  You're not really supposed to modify it in place.  That's what [`array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is for.

Comment: `map` is allowed to manipulate the array contents, but as a new array doesn't need to be created and returned you are right that `foreach` could be more appropriate.